# How to Find Tomorrow's And Yesterday's Date?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I want to find dates for today, tomorrow and yesterday, and I want to compare dates coming from backend and display "Today", "Tomorrow" and "Yesterday" respectively.

For today, I used:

```
var a = Date();
```

For tomorrow, I used:

```
var b = Date() + 1;
```

and For yesterday, I used:

```
var b = Date() - 1;
```

Hence, this is the complete code I have done in *formatter.js*

```
myDate: function(abc) {
  var oDateFormat;
  var requiredDate = oDateFormat.format(new Date(abc));
  var currentDate = oDateFormat.format(new Date());
  var tomorrowDate = oDateFormat.format(new Date() + 1);
  var yesterdayDate = oDateFormat.format(new Date() - 1);
  if (requiredDate === currentDate) {
    return "Today";
  } else if (requiredDate === tomorrowDate) {
    return "Tomorrow";
  } else if (requiredDate === yesterdayDate) {
    return "Yesterday";
  } else {
    return requiredDate;
  }
},
```

However, *tomorrow* and *yesterday* do not work. Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong? How can I compare dates with system date to find if its tomorrow or yesterday?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to display dates relatively, you just need to bind property with the Date(Time) `type` and the [format option `relative: true`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat).

E.g. https://embed.plnkr.co/Ec5jnK using JSONModel. Or in case of OData:

```xml
<DatePicker xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
  core:require="{ EdmDateTimeType: 'sap/ui/model/odata/type/DateTime' }"
  value="{
    path: 'myV2ODataModel>myDate',
    type: 'EdmDateTimeType',
    formatOptions: {
      relative: true
    },
    constraints: {
      displayFormat: 'Date'
    }
  }"
/>
```

[image: UI5 displaying relative date within date picker]

---

**PS:** currently, there is a bug in UI5 that fails to display `"yesterday"` or `"tomorrow"` instead of `"1 day ago"` or `"in 1 day"`: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2792

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code :

```
myDate: function(BackEndDate) {
        var currentDate   = new Date();
        var tomorrowDate  = new Date();
        var yesterdayDate = new Date();

        // Increase the date by 1 day
        tomorrowDate.setDate(tomorrowDate.getDate() + 1);

        // Decrease the date by 1 day
        yesterdayDate.setDate(yesterdayDate.getDate() - 1);

        if (BackEndDate === currentDate) {
            return "Today";
        }
        else if (BackEndDate === tomorrowDate) {
            return "Tomorrow";
        }
        else if (BackEndDate === yesterdayDate) {
            return "Yesterday";
        }

        else        
        {
            return BackEndDate;
        } 
    }
},
```

Comment: Hi Vivek.

this thing is working, however, if I try to format date using
 var oDateFormat = sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance({
    pattern: "EEE, MMM d"
   });

It shows me again same error that getDate() is not a function. I have to format the date so as to display it in frontend.